# Why I am getting negative integer equivalent of character

Tags: c

I am accepting space separated digits of number.
Then I am iterating over individual characters to get their integer equivalents as shown in below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    int numLength;
    printf("Enter number length: ");
    scanf("%d",&numLength);

    getchar();
    char str[2*numLength];
    printf("Enter number: ");
    fgets(str, 2*numLength, stdin);

    for(int i=0;i<2*numLength;i=i+2)
    {
        printf("%d ",('0'-*(str+i)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Below is sample output:

```
Enter number length: 5
Enter number: 2 k 6 a 0
-2 -59 -6 -49 0
```

My doubt is why it is giving negative of integer equivalents?

(You can run the code online [here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1Ii0zV9U))

Answer (score 3):

`'0' - '2'` is `-2` for the same reason that `0 - 2` is also `-2`: `'2'` is greater than `'0'` by 2, so the result of subtracting the greater from the lesser number is `-2`.

You want `*(str+i) - '0'` (or `str[i] -'0'`) if you want the result to be positive.

Comment: I had one more question, is the `char str[2*numLength];` safe? Does that work like a VLA? Because if not, then OP might face issues with writing and reading beyond limits.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj If the compiler supports VLAs, it will work fine (unless `numLength` is large enough to overflow the stack). Otherwise it won't compile. It's probably a better idea to allocate it dynamically though. It's better to avoid VLAs.

Comment: @MustafaAydın I referred to the array `str` being created. The size of the array might be unknown during runtime if VLAs are not supported. In OP's case, it might have worked since `numLength` might have some big value during runtime. Size of array aside, the memory allocated has no guarantee of having a null byte present, so the code has chances of running beyond bounds (including fgets). If lucky, there will be a segmentation fault.